# runing flink + hive example code throws 'Could not find a suitable table factory for 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.CatalogFactory' exception

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-flink

I'm new to flink.
trying to integrate flink with hive, runing this example code:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/hive/index.html

**sql-client-hive.yaml**:

```
execution:

    planner: blink
    current-catalog: myhive  # set the HiveCatalog as the current catalog of the session
    current-database: myhivedb

    
catalogs:

   - name: myhive
     type: hive
     hive-conf-dir: /opt/apache/hive/conf
```

`$ sql-client.sh embedded -d conf/sql-client-hive.yaml`

Reading default environment from: file:/opt/apache/flink-1.11.2/conf/sql-client-hive.yaml
No session environment specified.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClientException: Unexpected exception. This is a bug. Please consider filing an issue.
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.main(SqlClient.java:213)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.SqlExecutionException: Could not create execution context.
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.ExecutionContext$Builder.build(ExecutionContext.java:870)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.openSession(LocalExecutor.java:227)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.start(SqlClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.main(SqlClient.java:201)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.NoMatchingTableFactoryException: Could not find a suitable table factory for 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.CatalogFactory' in
the classpath.

Reason: Required context properties mismatch.

The following properties are requested:
hive-conf-dir=/opt/apache/hive/conf
type=hive

The following factories have been considered:
org.apache.flink.table.catalog.GenericInMemoryCatalogFactory
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableFactoryService.filterByContext(TableFactoryService.java:322)
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableFactoryService.filter(TableFactoryService.java:190)
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableFactoryService.findSingleInternal(TableFactoryService.java:143)
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableFactoryService.find(TableFactoryService.java:113)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.ExecutionContext.createCatalog(ExecutionContext.java:377)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.ExecutionContext.lambda$null$5(ExecutionContext.java:626)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.ExecutionContext.lambda$initializeCatalogs$6(ExecutionContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.ExecutionContext.wrapClassLoader(ExecutionContext.java:264)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.ExecutionContext.initializeCatalogs(ExecutionContext.java:624)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.ExecutionContext.initializeTableEnvironment(ExecutionContext.java:523)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.ExecutionContext.<init>(ExecutionContext.java:183)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.ExecutionContext.<init>(ExecutionContext.java:136)
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.ExecutionContext$Builder.build(ExecutionContext.java:859)
    ... 3 more
```

any idea what's going on?

Hive metastore running fine:

```
hive> SHOW DATABASES;
OK
default
myhivedb
Time taken: 0.05 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

**hive version**: `3.1.2`

**flink version**: `1.11.2`

Comment: also, when trying to run the python version of the code, below exception was thrown.   TypeError: Could not found the Java class 'org.apache.flink.table.catalog.hive.HiveCatalog'. The Java dependencies could be specified via command line argument '--jarfile' or the config option 'pipeline.jars'

Comment: Hi @Sean. Check if your hive path is really `/opt/apache/hive/conf` ? For example on my cluster it's in `/etc/hive/conf`. Also you should put `flink-sql-connector-hive-3.1.2_2.11-1.11.2.jar` to your Flink /lib folder with `hive-exec-3.1.0.jar` and `libfb303-0.9.3.jar`